# Cordova specific platform file

Tags: cordova, assets

I have 2 sound files:

```
Project/res/android/push.m4a
Project/res/ios/push.aiff
```

I would like to place each one to each platform (android ios respectively)

```
Project/platforms/android/assets/www/sounds/push.m4a
Project/platforms/ios/Project/www/sounds/push.aiff
```

I've tried to do it with no success in `config.xml` with

```
<asset src="res/android/push.m4a" target="sounds/push.m4a">
<resource-file src="res/android/push.m4a" target="sounds">
```

Any option to do so?

Comment: Are you using the CLI or PhoneGap Build?

Comment: I'm using cordova CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add those files using the `merges` folder.

Example:

```
//iOS
{project_path}/merges/ios/sounds/push.aiff

//Android
{project_path}/merges/android/sounds/push.m4a
```